# How do you selectively style checkboxes in R shiny with CSS according to their value?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

Is there a way you can specify a single checkbox from a group generated in R shiny to style using CSS?

I've got a block of 'parent' check boxes and I want to make it clear to the user which 'child' check boxes they control, so I'm attempting to fill each one with a different colour.

I'm only going to show the 'parent' checkboxes here for simplicity

R code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

items <- c("One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six")

runApp(
  list(ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    includeCSS("www/test_css.css"),
    h1("Hello World"),
    prettyCheckboxGroup('numbers',label="Choose numbers",choiceNames = items, choiceValues = items,selected = items),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )),
  server = shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
    output$value <- renderText(input$numbers)
  })

  ))
```

CSS code that works for all checkboxes together:

```
h1 {text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}

#numbers :after, #numbers :before{
  background-color:orange;
}
```

From looking at the HTML for the prettyCheckboxGroup, there's no ID for me to refer to, only values:

```
<div id="numbers" class="form-group shiny-input-checkboxgroup shiny-input-container">
  <label class="control-label" for="numbers">Choose numbers</label>
  <div class="shiny-options-group">
    <div style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="pretty p-default">
      <input type="checkbox" name="numbers" value="One" checked="checked"/>
      <div class="state">
        <label>
          <span>One</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:3px;"></div>
    <div class="pretty p-default">
      <input type="checkbox" name="numbers" value="Two" checked="checked"/>
      <div class="state">
        <label>
          <span>Two</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
etc...
```

I've tried various things like `input[value=One]` and `#numbers ~ input[value=One]`

As you can probably tell, I'm fairly new to CSS, any help would be much appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works with this CSS:

```css
.pretty input[value=One]~.state label:after, 
.pretty input[value=One]~.state label:before {
  background-color: orange !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect, it looks like it doesn't need the .pretty or the !important tags either (for now, until I want to add more specific CSS I guess)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign each `input` a unique CSS id using the `shinyjs` package as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

items <- c("One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six")

runApp(
  list(ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    includeCSS("css.css"),
    h1("Hello World"),
    prettyCheckboxGroup('numbers',label="Choose numbers",choiceNames = items, choiceValues = items,selected = items),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )),
  server = shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
    shinyjs::runjs(HTML('
    var inputs = $(".shiny-options-group").find(".p-default input");
                        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                        inputs[i].setAttribute("id", "input_" + i);
                        }
                        '))
    output$value <- renderText(input$numbers)
  })

  ))
```

The first `input` element in the checkbox group will have the ID `input_1`. You may now use this in your CSS file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I couldn't get it to work with just the id tag, but it did work really well with what Stephane replied with.

And it'll definitely be really useful to add more tags and classes to things as I work through things

Comment: Is there a way that you can create the IDs on the UI side? I'm currently trying to make some popovers for each child checkbox  so have given them all IDs using your script on the server side, however when I check a parent checkbox the IDs of the child checkboxes disappear and so the popover no longer works. 

I'll probably create a new question, but I thought I may as well ask here to see if you know first